# Can not mapping a controller with a path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this simple java Spring Boot project without any beans or persistency. I've created multiple packages to separate classes by functionality.

I read that controllers must be inside initial package NameApplication.java. However, I launch project on port 8080 and put next url localhost:8080/hello/grettings show me **Whitelabel Error Page** but I put localhost:8080 and load index.html

Why doesn't work?

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class BasicController {

    @GetMapping(path = {"/grettings", "/helloworld"})
    public String grettings() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# Application name.
spring.application.name=CursoSpring 

# Logging
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.com.globalomnium=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE

#Flyway
#spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true

# THYMELEAF
#spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
#spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
#spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
#spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
#spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html 
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false


# Server HTTP port.
server.port=8080
```

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId> 
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Package structure

[image]

Comment: can you add package structure too ?

Comment: sorry I forgot add the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CursoSpringApplication is the starting point of the application. when starting it searches for components such as @Controller, @Service, @Repository and @Component. Usually recommend that you locate your main application class in a root package above other classes. So this CursoSpringApplication class should be placed in most outer package. Change `com.globalomnium.axis.maps` to `com.globalomnium.axis`

**Example Structure**

```
com
 +- example
     +- myapplication
         +- Application.java
         |
         +- customer
         |   +- Customer.java
         |   +- CustomerController.java
         |   +- CustomerService.java
         |   +- CustomerRepository.java
         |
         +- order
             +- Order.java
             +- OrderController.java
             +- OrderService.java
             +- OrderRepository.java
```

[read more](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to check the Controller Bean is loading by changing your void main like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CursoSpringApplication.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }
```

You should see your bean "Basic Controller" listed in the console.
I would also place your CursoSpringApplication in the base package "com.globalomnium" instead of "com.globalomnium.axis.maps" so spring can handle all the annotated beans below the base package.

Hope it helps